# 'My question is about' ...the size of the Universe after Inflation

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

Hitherto, I had assumed, on account of Inflation, "boom" the Universe was "out there" and it has taken light 13.6 BY to get here.

However...

Quoting the aerospace engineer: 
 In my thinking if the universe was millimeters [or 340,000 LY] in size at the end of expansion, then the photons emitted from the "other side" of the universe would have passed us already.

Comment: I think you're imaging the universe has an edge (like an expanding balloon), but it's more like being **on** the surface if the expanding balloon - the surface gets bigger, everything gets further away  ("the surface=the universe").

Comment: I'm sure light from stars 340,000 light years and more away has moved past Earth for billions of years, but could you please specify your question?

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point Although it's not an exact duplicate, John's answer contains a lot of information relevant to this topic.

Comment: [The Big Bang didn't happen at a point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point)

Comment: This video could help you understand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIJTwYOZrGU&feature=share